# Can anyone explain how to use Mathematica's OAuth package?

Tags: interoperability, internet, networking, authentication

I noticed that in `HTTPClient.m` which is included with *Mathematica* 9 and is located in

```
FileNameJoin[{$InstallationDirectory, "SystemFiles", "Links", "HTTPClient"}]
```

there was a dependency on `` HTTPClient`OAuth` ``, so I poked around and found it.  `OAuth.m` seems to contain all of the necessary functions to perform OAuth authentication, which is interesting to me since I'd like to build an API manager for sites like fitbit, withings, etc. I managed to figure out that `SocialMediaData` uses OAuth (which makes sense, since that is the authentication method that I gather Facebook and Twitter require), but the code for that is hidden and trying to read `SocialMediaData.mx` only confirms that OAuth is used without showing me how it's called.

Can anyone figure out how to actually use `` HTTPClient`OAuth` `` in *Mathematica*?  Or perhaps can anyone figure out how to read the `SocialMediaData.mx` file to get the code for `SocialMediaData` so I can see how Wolfram made use of the package?

Comment: In v10, some online services have built-in interfaces using OAuth authentication, see [Accessing External Services & APIs](http://reference.wolfram.com/language/guide/AccessingExternalServicesAndAPIs.html).

Answer (score 22):

I now have part of the picture.  There is an undocumented function called `` HTTPClient`OAuthAuthentication[] `` which takes only options as arguments.  These options settings override defaults that are visible in `` HTTPClient`OAuth.m ``.  Here is an example of how to make get an OAuth 1.0a style access token, in this case for the Withings API:

```
token = HTTPClient`OAuthAuthentication[
  "ConsumerKey" -> "your_app_key", 
  "ConsumerSecret" -> "your_app_secret", 
  "RequestEndpoint" -> "https://oauth.withings.com/account/request_token",
  "AuthorizeEndpoint" -> "https://oauth.withings.com/account/authorize", 
  "AccessEndpoint" -> "https://oauth.withings.com/account/access_token"]
```

This will kick off the workflow for a desktop app, which means there is no callback URL (includes helpful dialog).  The Withings API chokes on this due to the lack of callback, but you can pull the necessary verifier from the URL of their attempted redirect.  The result of successfully obtaining an access token will be an `` HTTPClient`OAuthToken ``, which contains all of the necessary information to make properly authenticated calls to the API.   Here is an example of such a call:

```
url = "http://wbsapi.withings.net/measure?action=getmeas";
data = URLFetch[url, "OAuthAuthentication" -> token, 
  "Parameters" -> {"userid" -> "your_user_id"}];
```

This results in an http GET request with the oauth arguments supplied in the URL rather than as Authentication headers.  As you can see, you can apply additional parameters and even change the method to POST by supplying arguments to `URLFetch[]`.  This works for the Withings API, but some other APIs, like Fitbit, require headers.  I solved that problem by extending the open source java project called scribe (https://github.com/fernandezpablo85/scribe-java) so that *Mathematica* handles the authentication and scribe classes are called via `JLink` in order to make properly formatted calls.  If anyone can figure out how to modify `URLFetch[]` to get the headers into the proper form, it would be most helpful.

Here is an example of a token for OAuth 2.0:

```
token = HTTPClient`OAuthAuthentication[
  "ConsumerKey" -> "your_app_key", 
  "ConsumerSecret" -> "your_app_secret", 
  "AuthorizeEndpoint" -> "https://www.facebook.com/dialog/oauth", 
  "AccessEndpoint" -> "https://graph.facebook.com/oauth/access_token",
  "RedirectURI" -> None, 
  "OAuthVersion" -> "2.0"]
```

Notice there is no request endpoint and you must supply the version.  I also should note that I can't get this to work at the moment since I don't have a proper canvas URL as part of my Facebook app registration.

It is important to note that all of these functions are undocumented, so they are rather difficult to use and no doubt subject to change!

@rm -rf:  Thanks for reformatting and correcting my original question.  I tried to apply your wisdom here.

Note:  *Mathematica* v9.0.0 and *Mathematica* v9.0.1 seem to return different data structures after `` HTTPClient`OAuthAuthentication `` is used.  What you see above is from *Mathematica* v9.0.1.

UPDATE:

I am able to successfully add the authentication parameters to an Authorization header by doing the following:

```
URLFetch[url, 
 "Headers" -> {"Authorization" -> 
    "OAuth " <> 
     StringJoin[
      Riffle[{#[[1]] <> #[[2]] <> "\"" <> #[[3]] <> 
           "\""} & /@ (Riffle[#, "="] & /@ 
          Sort[StringSplit[#, "="] & /@ 
            StringSplit[
             StringSplit[
               HTTPClient`OAuthSignURL[
                 url,  {"CredentialsProvider" -> None, 
                  "OAuthAuthentication" -> token}][[1]], "?"][[2]], 
             "&"]]), ", "]]}]
```

Comment: I tried this with my Youtube Data API but it asks me for scope. Is there a way to give scope parameter to the ``OAuthSigning`OAuthAuthentication`` function? See my question https://mathematica.stackexchange.com/questions/200506/how-to-perform-oauth-2-0-authentication-in-mathematica

Answer (score 4):

In version 11 of Mathematica, I have used this (it's almost the same as Max's answer):

```
token = OAuthSigning`OAuthAuthentication[
  "ConsumerKey" -> "consumerkey", 
  "ConsumerSecret" -> "consumersecret", 
  "RequestEndpoint" -> "https://api.twitter.com/oauth/request_token", 
  "AuthorizeEndpoint" -> "https://api.twitter.com/oauth/authorize", 
  "AccessEndpoint" -> "https://api.twitter.com/oauth/access_token"]
```

Followed by:

```
URLRead[HTTPRequest[url, 
  "Headers" -> {"Authorization" -> 
     "OAuth " <> 
      StringJoin[
       Riffle[{#[[1]] <> #[[2]] <> "\"" <> #[[3]] <> 
            "\""} & /@ (Riffle[#, "="] & /@ 
           Sort[StringSplit[#, "="] & /@ 
             StringSplit[
              StringSplit[
                OAuthSigning`OAuthSignURL[
                  url, {"CredentialsProvider" -> None, 
                   "OAuthAuthentication" -> token}][[1]], "?"][[2]], 
              "&"]]), ", "]]}]]
```

The change is the name of the package changed to "OAuthSigning", the name of the function call to `URLRead` and the use of the `HTTPRequest` function.

Comment: I tried this with my Youtube Data API but it asks me for scope. Is there a way to give scope parameter to the ``OAuthSigning`OAuthAuthentication`` function? See my question https://mathematica.stackexchange.com/questions/200506/how-to-perform-oauth-2-0-authentication-in-mathematica