# Accessing Twitter API using Mathematica

Tags: social-media

How do interact with the Twitter API using Mathematica? SocialMediaData is a lovely function, but appears to be severely limited in what it can draw from Twitter. For example, if I want to get a list of retweets of a Tweet I've sent there's an API call for this but not a means of doing so through SocialMediaData. How do I augment the function with all the API has to offer?

Answer (score 9, accepted):

The Twitter API now requires Oauth 1.0a authentication, so Ragfield's `Twitter.m` won't work without modification.  While I haven't solved the problem for Twitter's API, I have solved two similar authentication problems from *Mathematica*.  You can see what I did here:

[Can anyone explain how to use Mathematica's OAuth package?](https://mathematica.stackexchange.com/questions/23279/can-anyone-explain-how-to-use-mathematicas-oauth-package)

UPDATE:

I just tried it with Twitter and this seemed to work:

```
token = HTTPClient`OAuthAuthentication[
   "ConsumerKey" -> "your_api_key", 
   "ConsumerSecret" -> "your_api_secret", 
   "RequestEndpoint" -> "https://api.twitter.com/oauth/request_token",
   "AuthorizeEndpoint" -> "https://api.twitter.com/oauth/authorize", 
   "AccessEndpoint" -> "https://api.twitter.com/oauth/access_token"];
url = "https://api.twitter.com/1.1/statuses/retweets_of_me.json";
URLFetch[url, "OAuthAuthentication" -> token]
```

I don't really know for sure since I don't have any retweets.

Comment: Very nice. Is there a way to tweak this so that it doesn't request verification through a Twitter account. In particular, If I already know the access token and access token secret, is there a way to pass that in to `HTTPClient\`OAuthAuthentication`?

Comment: Yes, here is what I use for fitbit, which will be the same for twitter:

``HTTPClient`OAuthToken[HTTPClient`OAuth`Private`OAuth10Parameters[
  "api.fitbit.com", None, Automatic, "verifier", Automatic, Automatic, 
  $FitbitConsumerKey, 
  $FitbitConsumerSecret, 
  "https://api.fitbit.com/oauth/request_token", "GET", 
  "https://www.fitbit.com/oauth/authorize", "RemoveWhitespace", 
  "https://api.fitbit.com/oauth/access_token", "GET", "HMAC-Sha1", 
  "HMAC", "oob", "Text/1.0", "Text/1.0", None], 
 HTTPClient`OAuth`Private`Token10[
  $FitbitUserKey, 
  $FitbitUserSecret]]``

Comment: OK... Wow. First, thank you! But how do you know what arguments to feed this function without documentation?

Comment: Is there a way to supply the oauth token and receive back not only the json contents but the header as well? Putting `URLFetch[url,{"Content","Headers"}, "OAuthAuthentication" -> token]` doesn't do the job...