# Import tweets from Twitter

Tags: import, social-media

Robert Raguet-Schofield in the [Mathematica Blog](http://blog.wolfram.com/2009/04/30/twittering-with-mathematica/) introduced a way to import tweets from Twitter into *Mathematica*.

I attempted to use this method. I started with this line of code:

```
xml = Import["https://twitter.com/statuses/user_timeline.xml?screen_name=WolframResearch"]
```

and received this message:

> FetchURL::httperr: The request to URL https://twitter.com/statuses/user_timeline.xml?screen_name=WolframResearch was not successful. The server returned the HTTP status code 404 ("Not Found").

Then I tried this

```
xml = Import["https://twitter.com/WolframResearch"]a
```

and this time I got some output. But when I continue the procedure to extract the tweets with this line

```
tweets = Cases[xml, XMLElement["text", _, {s_String}] :> s, ∞]
```

I get an empty set.

How can I import tweets into *Mathematica* in an effective way, given I am not a familiar with Apachi?

Comment: I think the Twitter API has changed a lot since that blog post. You'll probably need to look at the API documentation and start over.

Comment: It is true that the Twitter API has changed and the old one is deprecated. They now require the user to be authenticated, which makes it a bit more of a job retrieving tweets. MMA has `SocialMediaData` which lets you authenticate yourself and then get some data, but not tweets. It would be interesting to know if there was a way of using the MMA authentication to get other things from the API.

Comment: Using the second XML function as above, I could import some tweets but not all. And I know there is a function in R to do so. So it shoul be possible to implement it in Mathematica also.

Comment: @Morry Screen scraping can be done elegantly in a lot of languages, but it's harder in Mathematica because there aren't any really good libraries although it is absolutely possible. If you keep working with `Cases`, eventually you surely find a pattern that can yield all the tweets. APIs are always preferable if one can get them to work though.

Answer (score 3):

One first should access his developer account which is codded [here](https://mathematica.stackexchange.com/questions/23425/accessing-twitter-api-using-mathematica) as

```
token = HTTPClient`OAuthAuthentication[
   "ConsumerKey" -> "your_api_key", 
   "ConsumerSecret" -> "your_api_secret", 
   "RequestEndpoint" -> "https://api.twitter.com/oauth/request_token",
   "AuthorizeEndpoint" -> "https://api.twitter.com/oauth/authorize", 
   "AccessEndpoint" -> "https://api.twitter.com/oauth/access_token"];
url = "https://api.twitter.com/1.1/statuses/retweets_of_me.json";
URLFetch[url, "OAuthAuthentication" -> token]`
```

Then simply you should use API functions. As sample:

```
urlList = "https://api.twitter.com/1.1/lists/list.json?screen_name=BarackObama";
```

Then you should take the name of the Slug from the output and then

```
urlTweet = "https://api.twitter.com/1.1/lists/statuses.json?slug=ofa-legacy-conference&owner_screen_name=BarackObama&per_page=20&page=24"
xml = URLFetch[urlTweet, "OAuthAuthentication" -> token];
```

Then you need a simple `StringCases` analysis to get the tweets!

Comment: You figured it out. Great answer! :)

Answer (score 2):

Perhaps it should be mentioned that since this question was active, (prior to version 10) Mathematica has introduced `ServiceConnect` which allows a user to access the twittersphere and handles the authentication issue.  The documentation provides an example of importing tweets as the OP requested.

Comment: Could you include a valid example, for completeness?

Answer (score 0):

Here's a quick hack that nearly answers the question:

```
xml = Import["http://twitter.com/WolframResearch", "XMLObject"];
tweet = Cases[xml, 
  XMLElement[
    "p", {"class" -> "js-tweet-text tweet-text"}, {tweet__, 
     XMLElement["a", details__]}] :> {tweet, details }, Infinity]
```

resulting in:

```
{{"Perfect your parking moves with this new Wolfram Demonstration! ", 
 {"shape" -> "rect", "class" -> "twitter-timeline-link", 
   "dir" -> "ltr", "href" -> "http://t.co/YAa2poc8qi", 
   "rel" -> "nofollow", 
   "data-expanded-url" -> "http://wolfr.am/14dZd2G", 
   "target" -> "_blank", 
   "title" -> "http://wolfr.am/14dZd2G"}, {XMLElement[
    "span", {"class" -> "invisible"}, {"http://"}], 
   XMLElement["span", {"class" -> "tco-ellipsis"}, {}], 
   XMLElement[
    "span", {"class" -> "js-display-url"}, {"wolfr.am/14dZd2G"}], 
   XMLElement["span", {"class" -> "invisible"}, {}], 
   XMLElement[
    "span", {"class" -> "tco-ellipsis"}, {XMLElement[
      "span", {"class" -> 
        "invisible"}, {" "}]}]}},
{"In case you missed it, here's our latest blog post on using 
  Mathematica to do random walks of ", 
  XMLElement[

... and so on
```

Looks like there's hours of 'amusement' there if you like decoding Symbolic XML!

Comment: Is it possible to push the code in a way to extend the results to get the whole tweets? I mean what you proposed is just taking the first split of the tweets, not the whole history of tweets!!

Comment: I don't think they would do that. Without the Api you may be restricted. Google brings up many non-Mathematica discussions, eg [this one](http://osdir.com/ml/twitter-development-talk@googlegroups.com/2011-02/msg00215.html)