# Do any users know of methods to capture Twitter feeds and subject them to analysis?

Tags: graphs-and-networks, pattern-matching, social-media

I would like to use the output of about 300 Twitter sources and would probably collect 30 minutes of tweets at a time and subject each collection to analysis; ideally this process would be automatic and would update the statistical results every 30 minutes without the need for the user to instruct the program to analyze the latest collection.

I would welcome any suggestions or code examples that community members are willing to share relevant to my problem that have been written using Mathematica 9. I am also interested in any suggestions for analytical techniques that could be used on the resulting 30 minute collections.

Note: SocialMediaData[ ] does not help owing to a limitation caused by an error in the code that will be repaired in a future release, according to Wolfram tech support.

Thank you

Comment: You need to use the the Twitter API so you need to consult its documentation, for information about how to connect: http://mathematica.stackexchange.com/questions/28816/import-tweets-from-twitter, http://mathematica.stackexchange.com/questions/23425/accessing-twitter-api-using-mathematica

Answer (score 1):

The following [Wolfram Blog post](http://blog.wolfram.com/2009/04/30/twittering-with-mathematica/) covers Twitter Access in a pre-Version 9 Approach.

Comment: Nowadays it's possible (see comments) to connect to the Twitter API without using Java as this blog post does. The rest of the article is deprecated because the API it uses is deprecated.

Comment: Thank you Markus. I appreciate the reference.