# How to perform OAuth 2.0 Authentication in Mathematica?

Tags: authentication

I have been using the Youtube Data API v3 for sometime without any issue using `HTTPRequest` to send request by using Google API Key and `URLRead` to get the response in Mathematica. But for certain Youtube Data, Google requires OAuth 2.0 Authentication instead of a basic API Key. So I created the credentials online and got the `client_secret.json` file. Which contains:

```
{"installed":{
"client_id":"xxx.apps.googleusercontent.com",
"project_id":"xxx",
"auth_uri":"https://accounts.google.com/o/oauth2/auth",
"token_uri":"https://oauth2.googleapis.com/token",
"auth_provider_x509_cert_url":"https://www.googleapis.com/oauth2/v1/certs",
"client_secret":"xxx",
"redirect_uris":["urn:ietf:wg:oauth:2.0:oob","http://localhost"]
}}
```

All I want is to run the Mathematica's OAuth 2.0 feature to get the `token` to put in my endpoint URL when sending requests. How do I do that? I can't find anything in documentation in version 12. Maybe it is hidden in some context that I don't know.

Also I want the `scope` to be `"https://www.googleapis.com/auth/youtube"`.

---

Looking at [Can anyone explain how to use Mathematica's OAuth package?](https://mathematica.stackexchange.com/questions/23279/can-anyone-explain-how-to-use-mathematicas-oauth-package), I have tried the following:

```
token=OAuthSigning`OAuthAuthentication[
    "OAuthVersion"->"2.0",
    "AuthorizeEndpoint"->credentials["auth_uri"],
    "AccessEndpoint"->credentials["auth_provider_x509_cert_url"],
    "RedirectURI"->First[credentials["redirect_uris"]],
    "ConsumerKey"->credentials["client_id"],
    "ConsumerSecret"->credentials["client_secret"](*,
    "RequestEndpoint"->credentials["token_uri"]*)
]
```

where

```
credentials=Import[FileNameJoin[{NotebookDirectory[],"client_secret.json"}],"RawJSON"]["installed"]//Dataset
```

But it opens up the authentication dialog box with link to get the authentication code. On clicking the link, it gives me the following error:

```
400. That’s an error.

Error: invalid_request

Missing required parameter: scope
```

So my question is How do I give the scope parameter to the `` OAuthSigning`OAuthAuthentication `` function?

Comment: There's no great way to do this without making a full [service connection](https://mathematica.stackexchange.com/questions/146915/creating-a-custom-web-api-serviceconnection). You can check out how I did that for YouTube [here](https://b3m2a1.github.io/PacletServer/serviceconnectionyoutube.html).