# How to import a google sheets file that requires account login?

Tags: import, web-access, authentication

How do I import a google sheets file that is in my google drive?

I tried the following:

```
Import["https://docs.google.com/spreadsheets/d/...file...id...",Authentication-><|"Username"->"...@gmail.com","Password"->"..."|>]
```

When I try this I get the following output:

> One account. All of Google.     Sign in to continue to Sheets
>
> Enter your email                  Find my account              Sign in
> with a different account         Create account         One Google
> Account for everything Google
>
> About Google       Privacy       Terms       Help

I am signed into my google account in my browser.

Comment: Not to avoid the main issue you want to solve, but why not make the file publicly available via a shared link that does not require authentication?

Comment: @CATrevillian It's a business account with internal files and I am not allowed to make the files public.

Comment: Google uses OAuth, `SecuredAuthenticationKey` is probably the most relevant Mathematica thing to look at.  Maybe see https://developers.google.com/sheets/api/.  Also https://mathematica.stackexchange.com/questions/200506/how-to-perform-oauth-2-0-authentication-in-mathematica.

Comment: @Adam does `SecuredAuthenticationKey` support `OAuth 2.0`? There is no example showing it and no option parameter to use `OAuth 2.0` in the documentation.

Answer (score 2):

I had a similar problem trying to open a google sheet file shared with me. By selecting "SHARE" in google Drive and share the file for "Anyone with the link."
Then Import["https://docs.google.com/spreadsheets/d/.../export?format=csv","Data"];

I hope that this helps.